# Perturbation in the equation $u_t=\epsilon Pu$, where $P$ is an elliptic partial differential operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, linear-pde, perturbation-theory, generalized-functions

Let $Pu=\sum_{ij} \partial_j(a_{ij}(x) \partial_{i} u)$ be an elliptic operator. Consider the equation
$$
(u=u_\epsilon)\\
\partial_t u=\epsilon Pu \text{ in } \mathbb R^+ \times \Omega,\\
u(0,x)=u_0(x), u(t,x)=0\text{ for }x \in \partial\Omega
$$
where $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ (not necessarily bounded).

A weak solution to this equation exists and is unique in $L^2(0,T,H_0^1(\Omega))$.

Let $u_\epsilon$ be the solution to the equation corresponding to the given value of $\epsilon$. I wish to show that when $\epsilon \to 0$, $u_\epsilon$ converges in $L^2$ to a limit $u$.

By checking the formulation of a weak solution ($\chi$ is a test function, for example, in $C^1$):
$$
\int u_\epsilon \partial_t \chi=-\epsilon\int  (\nabla u) A (\nabla\chi),
$$
we could show that $u_\epsilon$ is bounded in the $H^1$ norm for $\epsilon<1/2$, and hence that
$$
\int (\partial_tu_{\epsilon_1}-\partial_tu_{\epsilon_2}) \chi \to 0 
$$
as $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \to 0$, for every test function $\chi$. Hence $u_\epsilon$ converges to a distributional limit.

**Question: is it ture that $u_\epsilon$ converges almost everywhere to a limit $u$?** This is true in the case of $Pu=\Delta u$ by direct computation, after writing out the solution explicitly as an integral (heat equation). But in the general case, how could I prove the same result?

Comment: Wouldn't a limit $u=u_0$ and in the case $u_0$ has no derivatives there would be no convergence of $\partial_j u_\epsilon$?

Comment: @Andrew I have now fixed the problem. In fact, I am just expecting convergence in some sense.

Comment: As said by @Andrew, if $u$ is the solution for $\epsilon=1$, then $u_\epsilon (t)=u(\epsilon t)$.

Comment: Depending on the particular applications you're interested in you might want to look at Eberhard Hopf "The partial differential equation $u_t+uu_x=\mu u_{xx}$" Comm. Pure Appl. Math. 3 (1950), no. 3, 201-230, or S.N. Kruzkov "First order quasilinear equations in several independent variables," which are concerned with these kinds of questions